# FileSaver.js -.saveAs: How to add listeners

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js, browser-nativefs

My code (I would have made this runnable except for the filesaver.js dependency (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/))

```
  var array = new Array();
  array[0] = 'a'; //.replace(/<br>/g, '\n\t');
  var blob = new Blob(array, {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

  var pub = function () {
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(new Error().stack);
  }

    let loc = window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    let obj = window.saveAs(blob, loc);
    obj.onwriteend = pub;
//    obj.onerror = pub;
    obj.onabort = pub;
```

There is no issue with the file saving

The issues are that the onwriteend handler gets called before I've even picked a file, and onabort never gets called. I don't know what's going on here. I'm trying to get a callback when the content is written to disk or when the file chooser is aborted.

Comment: It looks like when this js file is loaded, everything after `let loc = ...` gets triggered immediately, so you want to wrap those in an `EventListener`, as you've mentioned, based on what you want the trigger to be. I'm assuming this is for a website? But without more of the code, it'd be hard to tell exactly what change you need to make. If you want it to be triggered after clicking a `button`, surround the mentioned code in a method, then on the trigger `button`, add the following property `onclick="methodName()"`

Comment: @Sal It is actually run in a (button "click") EventListener. The Object obj returned from saveAs has fields for several listeners including onwriteend and onabort. And like I said the onwriteend event *is* getting triggered, just before I've picked a file and before the file writing has even started (confirmed with via the error.stack message and a breakpoint on the line in FileSaver.js)

Comment: In that case, please provide all relevant code so that we can see what's happening, including the HTML and any other javascript that could be relevant

Comment: you must be using an older version if filesaver.js, same as the one I'm using, and you'll find that if filesaver.js can use the "save link" method, then `writestart`, `progress`, `write, and `writeend` are dispatched at once as soon as the download is initiated

Comment: @JaromandaX I might be using an old version. Is the version in the GitHub project I included above up to date? If not, where can I find the new version?

Comment: the version you linked to does not seem to dispatch any of the above events ... version 1.x does, but you linked to the latest 2.x

Comment: @JaromandaX So effectively, it seems like neither version truly supports events as I'd like to listen for, or?

Comment: correct - since it is very likely the `save link` method is being used anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSaver.js is limited by its use of the `save link` tunnel: It's declared listeners do not work, and there is no way to get the name and directory of saved file, or even to know if the file was saved at all.

Using browser-nativefs instead of FileSaver.js is good in that it uses established FileHandler / File API. But browser-nativefs is too limited for my purposes: You cannot get the directory / URI / URL of the file download. The only way to provide this "link" is through the (FileSave.js) browser file download process outside of the scope of what JavaScript can see.